# SignalR server errors with more then one client

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a SignalR LoginHub with a Login method.

I have a client that connects and successfully calls Login.  I then restart my client and reconnect and once again successfully call Login.  As soon as I do this, the server side starts throwing the following error every 10 seconds on the dot:

`An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Web.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary`

This error only starts happening if my Login function attempts to call a client side function, such as `Clients.SendMessage("test")`.  If I remove the SendMessage broadcast, there are no errors!

Login Hub:

```
public class LoginHub : Hub
    {
        public void Login(AuthenticationObject _authObject)
        {
            Clients.SendTestMessage("woo");
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you need to clean up a client reference somewhere, but without some code it's really hard to tell.

Comment: Does it cause an exception to be thrown when the server runs (ie. does the server application crash?)  This might just be something that's normal and only visible in the debugger.

Comment: No, the server does not crash..I would just like to be able to log and fix any exceptions my app throws...

Comment: My guess is this isn't a real exception, rather it's something that SignalR catches and handles itself, so there's nothing for you to catch or log.  I'm definitely no SignalR expert, but I'm just making and educated guess.

Comment: Please show us your code where the client-side `SendMessage` method is defined and the server-side Login method called.